# How to remove last 7 bytes from a file in C?

Tags: c, loops

I want to generate exactly 125000000 bytes or 10^9 bits of random numbers but instead, I end up with  125000007 bytes of data. How to cut off the last 7 bytes from the file?

I tried this

```
int truncate(const char *path, off_t length);
truncate("/tmp/F.bin", 7);
```

This is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


union
{
    unsigned int uc;
    unsigned char byte[4];
} rand_data;

int main(){

        FILE * fp;

        fp = fopen("/tmp/F.bin", "wb");
        unsigned int size = 0;

        srand(501459);
        while(size <= 125000000) {
            rand_data.uc = rand();
            fprintf(fp, "%x%x%x%x", rand_data.byte[3], rand_data.byte[2], rand_data.byte[1], rand_data.byte[0]);
            size = ftell(fp);
        }
        printf("%d", size);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why `'5'` instead of `5`? Also, the second parameter in `truncate` is the size of the resulting file, not the bytes you want removed.

Comment: `while(size <= 124999993)` ?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Either '5' or 5 displays an error.

Comment: @EgzonKorenica in general, when you get an error you should tell us what it is if you need help with that.

Comment: @TheCodingPenguin Yep tried that but it gets me 124999999. So it's either 124999999 or 125000007

Comment: @EgzonKorenica  `124999994` then ?

Comment: If you are using `%x`, your data is not at all random but highly skewed.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It was an error due to using ' instead of " in the path, I changed that i get no error but no result I wanted either.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes `%x` produces one digit and mostly produces two digits. If you used `%.2x` or `%02x`, it would always produce two digits.  Then you wouldn’t run into the erratic file lengths.

Comment: @TheCodingPenguin still the same issue.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That solved my issue. Thanks a lot, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`%x` seems the wrong format specifier for this job as it may write more than one byte.

Try using `%c` instead.

Also I wonder why you are using `ftell`. I would go for:

```
size += 4;
```

instead.

Perhaps a loop like:

```
    while(size < 4*31250000) {
        rand_data.uc = rand();
        fputc(rand_data.byte[3], fp);
        fputc(rand_data.byte[2], fp);
        fputc(rand_data.byte[1], fp);
        fputc(rand_data.byte[0], fp);
        size += 4;
    }
```

Comment: No, don't use `%c`.  Don't use `printf` at all.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change my condition to size < 125000000 and also %x to %02x as recommended. :)

Comment: in that case, kill the union and output:
`fprintf(fp, "%08x", rand_data.uc );`

Comment: @JohnH Fair enough.